# what to do if i need to use in spring boot Criteria builder or jpa Specifications with my native query?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jpa, criteria-api, primeng-datatable

I am using angular in front-end and there I am using prime-ng table with lazy loading so I have to filter my data in the back-end (spring boot) I already have my queries in the back-end I just need to Specifications or criteria builder or any other thing to filter the data with the query what should I do?

Comment: If you are using native queries you cannot use Criteria API (Specification is also Critieria API)

Comment: i have some native queries and some jpql what do u think I should do

Comment: If you want to use Criteria API you have to re-write these queries

Comment: is there is any other way to have a dynamic filtering for my data?

Comment: Do you mean something liket this? https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.6/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#pc-filter